How to cancel an alarm properly?
I am trying to write a simple alarm app, but I can't cancel an alarm after I register it.
I have read multiple threads about the use of alarmmanager on the stackoverflow and I know that I have to make sure pendingintents have same flag, intent, action and request code to cancel an alarm. However, I can't figure out what makes my pendingintent different from each other. (The requestcode(id) should be the same. I checked this by Log.d() method)
 public void onSwitchChanged(int id,MaterialSwitch aSwitch, boolean isChecked) {
            //Update switch button and store it in room
            Alarm regAlarm = alarmModel.getSingleAlarm(id);
            regAlarm.setEnabled(isChecked);
            alarmModel.updateAlarm(regAlarm);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    
            //Turn stored time into ms
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();
            target.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR),now.get(Calendar.MONTH),now.get(Calendar.DATE),regAlarm.getHour(),regAlarm.getMinute(),0);
            long targetTime = target.getTimeInMillis();
    
            //Intent settings
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    
            //alarm manager registration
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),id,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            if(isChecked){
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,targetTime,pendingIntent);
                temp = pendingIntent;
            }
            else {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                //if(temp!=null)Log.d("test",String.valueOf(temp.equals(pendingIntent))); this returns false
            }
        }

Edit:
I found that this is due to my mistake. I have another register alarm function in another activity but with different pendingIntent flags so I cannot cancel an alarm through the code above.
I also found a function to do the same thing but with better performance called "setAlarmClock()". This method can wake the device, providing more accurate triggering. Hope this can help those who are in need.
